# Cannot find custom compiled 'CMake'

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, cmake, centos

I ran into a strange issue today and I hope someone will be able to steer me to the right direction. I am trying to compile hiphop-php and it requires cmake version 2.8.5.

I am not a root user, so I am unable to just upgrade cmake install it on the server level. So, what I ended up doing is download cmake source and compiled it myself on my home directory.

Here's how I compiled cmake to my home directory

```
./configure --prefix=~/Applications/cmake/
make && make install
```

So, when i do

```
cd ~/Applications/cmake/bin
./cmake -version
```

I see `cmake version 2.8.11.2`.

But here is the kicker!

I updated my `~/.tchrc` file to include the cmake path like below:

```
setenv PATH "${PATH}:~/Applications/cmake/bin"
```

When I do `echo $PATH` on the terminal I get:

`/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:
  /usr/local/bin:
  /usr/bin:
  /bin:
  ~/Applications/cmake/bin:`

But when I do `which cmake` it still shows `/usr/bin/cmake`.

Why is it not using the cmake under `~/Applications/cmake/bin`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is it not using the cmake under ~/Applications/cmake/bin?

Because /usr/bin comes before ~/Applications/cmake/bin in your PATH. The PATH is searched from left to right.

Put ~/Applications/cmake/bin in front:

```
   setenv PATH "~/Applications/cmake/bin:${PATH}"
```

Comment: Thanks buddy... you and Anycorn posted the answer almost simultaneously!

Answer (score 2):

Because `/usr/bin` appears first and takes precedence over  `~/Applications/cmake/bin`.

You want

```
setenv PATH "~/Applications/cmake/bin:${PATH}"
```